# Finding a Gradient Vector given only a derivative and direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've seen this question answered but in $2$ variables (which means you have two equations and two unknowns and can solve simultaneously), but not this variation, and I'm stuck.

So given that the derivative of $f(x,y,z)$ at $P$ is greatest in direction $\vec{A} = \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} - \mathbf{k}$ and is $2\sqrt{3}$, find the gradient of $f$.

At first I tried simply turning $\vec{A}$ into a unit vector, which becomes $\left\langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right\rangle$, and dividing the directional derivative by the unit vector, but I was getting the wrong answer and realized that dividing by a vector is a no-no.

I also tried multiplying out delF =  by my unit vector from above and setting equal to $2\sqrt{3}$ but then I can only get an answer by guessing, which I know isn't an acceptable method (for the purposes of my math class).

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "derivative of $f(x,y,z)$ at P"?

Comment: the rate of change is largest in the direction of the gradient and that maximum value is the magnitude of the gradient. Thus, multiply your unit vector by $2 \sqrt{3}$ and that's the gradient.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I am not sure about " ... at P" part of the sentence. What is P?

Comment: @Vlad just the point in question, but, since we are given the direction and magnitude for $(\nabla f)(P)$ neither the formula for $f$ nor the details of $P$ particularly matter. That was my knee-jerk read of this.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook thank you